Struggling with stuttering in my 2D C++/OpenGL game
I'm building a 2D game from scratch using C++ and OpenGL, but I've run into a frustrating issue: a simple sprite moving from left to right occasionally stutters. Tracking down the cause has been challenging. Is it my game loop? OpenGL? My code? Something else entirely?
I know there are many posts about stuttering, but I haven’t found any that provide helpful insights for my situation (linux).
There are two kind of stutter :
There are two types of stutter I'm observing:

Mini bumps every few seconds: I suspect this might be caused by inaccuracies in my loop, possibly due to the accumulator leading to occasional double updates.
Persistent shaking: Sometimes the sprite jitters left and right for several seconds. This is the issue I most want to fix or at least understand.

What I've tried
Recording the issue has been difficult. When I use OBS to capture it, the stutter often disappears when I move the game window or perform other tasks. I’ve also tried recording with my phone, but the stuttering is hard to notice in the footage (blur and focus).
I’ve uploaded the loop I use here on GitHub. Which is the implementation of Tyler Glaiel.
My setup

OS: Archlinux (6.12.4-arch1-1)
GPU: ASUS GeForce DUAL GTX 1060 O6G

Steps I’ve taken so Far

Enabled VSync: No noticeable improvement
Tried multiple game loop implementations

Fix Your Timestep!
How to make your game run at 60fps
Various custom loops found online


Tested on Windows (D3D11): While it stutters less, I prefer to stick with OpenGL on Arch Linux and fix the issue.
Used interpolation on rendering: No change.
Tested on another PC: I have other problem like screen tearing (I also have this on the current PC but it's less frequent)
Tried other languages: I experimented with C#, but the stuttering occurred there as well.
Used different libraries: To eliminate potential culprits, I tested with both GLFW and SDL.

What I’m Looking For
I don't expect a miracle solution, but I'd appreciate any suggestions to help me debug and identify the root cause.

What can I try next?
How can I effectively debug this?
Should I just accept and ignore the stuttering for now?

Thank you in advance for your help!

To help with debugging, we typically need a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: enough code to see how you're timing your game loop and how you're moving your sprites / viewpoint. That'll help us spot if you're making any errors in these areas. That code should be embedded in the body of your question, not linked off-site (where it might change or go offline in future).

Could you record your sprite shaking? Have you tried using a profiler and see where the time is used when the hitch happens? Does it happen both in Debug and Release?
Have you enabled Debug Callbacks and ensured all your OpenGL state is correctly set?
